# Installing Laravel/Homestead On Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, vagrant

While installing Laravel/Homestead on Ubuntu 15.1 I can't get my path mapped correctly in order to run "vagrant up" any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
 goldenos@GoldenOS:~/Homestead$ vagrant up
 Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
 There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
 the following errors and try again:

  vm: * The host path of the shared folder is missing:~/home/goldenos/Homestead/projects
```

This is the configuration of my Homestead.yaml file

```
   ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: ~/home/goldenos/Homestead/projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/goldenos/Homestead/projects

databases:
- homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar 
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Comment: This seems like an incorrect path: `map: ~/home/goldenos/Homestead/projects`.  Can you navigate to that path on your Ubuntu machine to verify that it exists?  If not, try `~/Homestead/projects`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `~` is the shortcut for `/home/username` in Linux so either remove the `~` in your path or remove the `/home/username` part.

Use either:

```
folders:
  - map: ~/Homestead/projects
    to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

or

```
folders:
  - map: /home/goldenos/Homestead/projects
    to: /home/vagrant/Code
```